# FingerPrint Reader - Problem with create event handler from C# code to C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, sdk, clr

I bought an FingerPrint Reader to my program.
I download the SDK for it and and I have problem with convert code in C# to CLR.

Code in C# and this is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1psU4DLJSmI) that I use.

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form, Capture.Capture.EventHandler
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I try something like this:

```
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form , DPFPEventHandlerStatus^ EH;
    {
        DPFPCapture^ Cp;
        DPFPSample^ Sample;
        DPFPSampleConversion^ Conver;
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: W tym miejscu dodaj kod konstruktora
            //
            Cp->StartCapture;


        }
```

```
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form , DPFPCapture->EventHandler
    {
        DPFPCapture^ Cp;
        DPFPSample^ Sample;
        DPFPSampleConversion^ Conver;
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: W tym miejscu dodaj kod konstruktora
            //
            Cp->StartCapture;


        }
```

How can I create this event handler?

Comment: Hi @Krzywy. Thanks for posting. When asking a question it is good to post as much information as possible. What have you tried in C#. What errors did you get? Start with learning a bit about EventHandlers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/creating-event-handlers-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 0):

You can attach methods to events like this:

```
Cp.The_Event += The_Event;
```

Example method:

```
private void The_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add references you need? 
Based on video, MyForm should be a partial class of: `DPFP.Capture.EventHandler`. Its managed  c++ equivalent is: `DPFP::Capture::EventHandler`. Dots doesn't provide acces to namespaces and classes in managed c++. To access namespaces and classes use `::`